# JS Array value renders undefined, so Uncaught type Error occurs

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, ejs

This code works for the most part, changing display of elements according to their array value according to the classname.  The result on the page worked for the most part but the browser renders an err nonetheless and i'm unable to get all of the elements in the classes displays to change which is desired if my user selects "select all".  I am really close.

```
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('check')[0].checked == true) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "inline-block";
        x[i].scrollIntoView;
    }
    // Code Breaks
    for (i = 11; i++;) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    // Code Breaks END 
    return;
};
```

Once again, the end result is almost right, butI think for select all to work I just need to change the values and add another if statements within their parent for loops.  LMK what you all think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do here:

```
// Code Breaks
    for (i = 11; i++;) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
// Code Breaks END
```

But in the first loop you're already accessing every element with the class 'data', so what is the problem again?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out just needed another for loop with && I am that dumb.